# Переименовать файлы массово с условием

Tags: windows, файлы

Есть папка с файлами, фото, названия файлов имеют такой вид:

```
12345-abcdefgh-ijklmnopqrtuvwxyz
```

Мне нужно как-то привести все названия файлов к виду:

```
12345
```

То есть оставить только первые цифры в названии файла (их пять, это типа артикул).

Хотелось бы как-то решить каким-нибудь тотал командером или вроде того. Уже победил похожую задачу с текстом в файле, там регулярками в notepad сделал, а вот как с файлами это решать — не знаю.

Comment: НУ наверно цифры будут повторяться, что с ними делать?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/dist/File-Rename/view/source/rename

Comment: в зависимости от других требований можно написать срипт, который все это сделает, или поставить какую-нибудь программу типа [RenameMaster](https://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/) и переименовать в ней (в данном случае просто обрезать имя до пяти символов). Можно и в тотал коммандере - выделить файлы, нажать Ctrl-M (или меню Files - Multi-Rename tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тотал коммандере выделить нужные файлы, потом меню Files - Multi-Rename Tool или нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. И там уже можно использовать регулярку.

Comment: Спасибо, там вообще просто всё, [N1-5] и погнали. Пара дублей нашлось всего лишь, все заняло несколько секунд.